# Continuing the loop

Tags: python-2.7, loops, ping, python-2.6, nslookup

Ok so I have code that is supposed to run through a txt file and ping the Ip's  if the ping is equal to 0 its does an 'nslookup' on it and then it's supposed to continue but after it does the first one in the terminal it's left on a > as if waiting for input. In other instances, my code runs through the txt file fine but once I added in the 'nslookup' it stops after the first one and waits for input.

Is there a way to make it continue to cycle through the txt file till it gets to the end?

Heres the code I'm using I know there are other ways to do a look up on an Ip address but I'm trying to use 'nslookup' in this case unless its impossible.

```
import os
with open('test.txt','r') as f:
  for line in f:
         response = os.system("ping -c 1 " + line)
         if response == 0:
                 print os.system('nslookup')
         else:
                 print(line, "is down!")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that's simply because you forgot to pass the argument to `nslookup`

When you don't pass any argument, the program starts in interactive mode with its own shell.

```
L:\so>nslookup
Default server :   mydomain.server.com
Address:  128.1.34.82

>
```

But using `os.system` won't make you able to get the output of the command. For that you would need

```
output = subprocess.check_output(['nslookup',line.strip()])
print(output) # or do something else with it
```

instead of your `os.system` command

Comment: Ok so when I im put os.system('nslookup {}'.format(line.strip())) I get File "<stdin>", line 5, in <module>
ValueError: zero length field name in format

Comment: Funny enough it works in 2.7 the orginal way you had it but the systems im going to be using it on run 2.6. Thank tiy very much though extremly helpful.